# Twig 'for each' search result - my code controls all search results whereas it should run for each result

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I have multiple post types working in my (Relevanssi) search results such as news, blog, companies etc. The search output displays: title, date, featured image and summary. However, I need the date field to be different for companies; so for every other post type the post date output is fine, but for companies I need the date output to be a line of text (can be hardcoded).

The search feature is controlled in my feed.twig file. It starts {% for item in feed %} then runs a bunch of arguments such as:

```
{% if item.image %}
<a href="{{ item.path }}" class="item-image">
<picture>
{{ item.image|responsive_image('card_image', 'card_image_desktop_1x', 'object-fit') }}
</picture></a>
{% endif %}
```

This basically translates to if post type has an image, then populate the search result template with that image. If the post type doesn't have an image, then don't display the image field on the search result.

This works in the same way for title, date and summary.

To control the different dates for companies, I have added an acf field (true/false) so that if it is ticked, the date outputs the custom text, if it isn't ticked then the date outputs as post date. Here is my code for date:

```
{% if post.meta('show_text_for_date') == true and item.date %}
<span class="item-header-date">CUSTOM DATE TEXT HERE</span>
{% elseif post.meta('show_text_for_date') == false and item.date %}
<span class="item-header-date"><time datetime="{{ item.date|date("Y-m-d") }}">item.date|date("jS F Y") }}</time></span>
{% endif %}
```

This translates to, if the acf tick box is ticked, and the post type has a date, populate the date field with the hardcoded text. If the acf field isn't ticked and the post type has a date, populate the date field with the post date.

This works, however it queries the argument on the very first search result and applies that to each search result thereafter. So if there is one search return it will work correctly, if there are multiple search returns the argument on the first return will control the date output on the rest.

My (long!) question is, how do I run that date argument on every single search result rather than just running it on the first which then controls the rest?

Any help would be very appreciated, I am totally stuck on this!

Thank you

search.php:

```
// Search
$context['feed'] = array();
foreach ( $search_results as $search_result ) {
    $image = false;
    // Image
    $components = get_field( 'components', $search_result->ID );
    if ( $components[0]['acf_fc_layout'] === 'hero' && !empty( $components[0]['image'] ) ) {
        $image = $components[0]['image']['ID'];
    } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail( $search_result->ID ) ) {
        $image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $search_result->ID );
    }

    
    $context['feed'][] = array(
        'title'   => $search_result->post_title,
        'summary' => get_the_excerpt( $search_result->ID ),
        'path'    => get_the_permalink( $search_result->ID ),
        'image'   => $image,
        'label'   => '',
        'label_path' => '',
        'date'    =>  '',
    );
    
}
```

Comment: Isn't it should be item.meta not post.meta?

Comment: Thank you - I have tried item.meta and it doesn't work. The acf tick box is within the post, it doesn't pick it up when I use item. The argument is working, if there is one result it does work, I just need the argument to loop through every search result which currently it isn't doing.

Comment: Every item has the property `date` then?

Comment: Yes every item has a date as it is a post or page. I'm not sure why the argument 'if date' is written that way because every item will always have a date. If I remove the 'if date' argument though the date output doesn't work so it is needed.

Comment: I think you little overcomplicated your code. `Timber\Post` has access to it's post_type, so it will be like `{% if( item.post_type is same as 'companies' ) %}` then show hardcoded date. No need to create extra ACF field. But if you need it than try to dump item.meta (why it doesn't work) and post.meta. Also need to know what is post context.

Comment: Thank you - I agree it is probably overcomplicated, though the argument itself I don't think is the issue it is applying that argument to each individual search result which is the issue. To try the if statement you suggested, how do I wrap that if within the {% if item.date %} tag?

Comment: item.date should always return 'true' (it will return date string which in if statement should be non-empty string == true) so I don't think you need to check it

Comment: Agreed, but if I don't first run {% if item.date %} then no date output occurs. I have to run that if statement to get the date output to display. Any code to control how the date output works has to be within the {% if item.date %} statement.

Comment: No you don't need to do it. You can simply output `{{ item.date }}`. To correct display output for companies post type all you need is to check for this post type to be companies nothing more

Comment: Still doesn't work, the argument resolves on the first search return and governs each return thereafter :( no version of the argument seems to change this. Could it be to do with the search.php file? I have add the php code to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I see your feed context is not `Timber\PostQuery` so it has no idea what meta is. By default Timber provides `posts` context on every page so it will be like `{% for item in posts %}`. This way item.meta should work.

Comment: Also don't know what is $search_results - I would suggest you to use `Timber::get_posts` to recieve feed context directly